# How do I get private instance variables into another class via inheritance (extends)?

Tags: java

I'm trying my hand at inheritance for the first time and I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around this.

Basically I have a Customer class and a WarrantyCustomer class. WarrantyCustomer says that the customer has a warranty and should be given a discount.

My Customer looks like this (not the whole class)

```
public class Customer {
    private int monthsSinceVisit;
    private double totalVisitCost;  

    (public constructor is here)

    public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
        return monthsSinceVisit;
    }

    public double getTotalVisitCost(){
        return totalVisitCost;
    }  

    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        totalVisitCost = 20.00 + (12.00*monthsSinceVisit);
        return totalVisitCost;
    }
}
```

And then in WarrantyCustomer I have:

```
public class WarrantyCustomer extends Customer {
    private int monthsSinceDiscount;
    
    @Override
    public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
        return super.getMonthsSinceVisit();
    }
    
    @Override
    public double getTotalVisitCost(){
        return super.getTotalVisitCost();
    }

    (public constructor is here)

    @Override
    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        while (monthsSinceDiscount>=12){
            totalVisitCost = ((20.00 + (12.00*monthsSinceVisit)) * 0.20);
            monthsSinceDiscount = 0;

        }
        return totalVisitCost;
    }
}
```

I am unsure of why in my getNextVisitCost() in WarrantyCustomer it tells me that totalVisitCost and monthsSinceVisit are private in Customer. I know they are private but I thought I brought them into this class with my getter methods.

Thank you for any help. For this I am not permitted to set my instance variable to public or protected.

Comment: Remember, your getter methods are public.

Comment: You should define setter methods for that 2 variable in customer class, which methods can be protected or public.

Comment: Is there a reason why my getters do not work? And what should my setters look like, what should they return? monthsSinceVisit is already set equal to 0 in Customer's constructor so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this problem you should define a setter for your `totalVisitCost` and then access it in subclass:

```
public class Customer {
    private int monthsSinceVisit;
    private double totalVisitCost;  
    
    
    public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
        return monthsSinceVisit;
    }

    public double getTotalVisitCost(){
        return totalVisitCost;
    }  
    
    protected void setTotalVisitCost(double totalVisitCost) {
        this.totalVisitCost = totalVisitCost;
    }
    
    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        totalVisitCost = 20.00 + (12.00*monthsSinceVisit);
        return totalVisitCost;
    }
}
```

```
public class WarrantyCustomer extends Customer {
    private int monthsSinceDiscount;
    
    @Override
    public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
        return super.getMonthsSinceVisit();
    }
    
    @Override
    public double getTotalVisitCost(){
        return super.getTotalVisitCost();
    }
    
    @Override
    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        while (monthsSinceDiscount>=12){
            setTotalVisitCost(((20.00 + (12.00*getMonthsSinceVisit())) * 0.20));
            monthsSinceDiscount = 0;
        }
        return getTotalVisitCost();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `WarrantyCustomer` is already inheriting the getters and setters from `Customer` and you don't need to modify them, you don't need to override them.

But the problem was you were trying to set the value of the `totalVisitCost` directly, instead of creating a setter and using it in the child class.

```java
public class Customer {
    private int monthsSinceVisit;
    private double totalVisitCost;  

    // (public constructor is here)

    public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
        return monthsSinceVisit;
    }

    public double getTotalVisitCost(){
        return totalVisitCost;
    }  
    
    // public setter for the private totalVisitCost
    public void setTotalVisitCost(double cost) {
        totalVisitCost = cost;
    }

    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        totalVisitCost = 20.00 + (12.00*monthsSinceVisit);
        return totalVisitCost;
    }
}

public class WarrantyCustomer extends Customer {
    private int monthsSinceDiscount;

    // Don't need these overrides, it's already inherited.
    // @Override
    // public int getMonthsSinceVisit(){
    //     return super.getMonthsSinceVisit();
    // }
    
    // @Override
    // public double getTotalVisitCost(){
    //     return super.getTotalVisitCost();
    // }

    @Override
    public double getNextVisitCost(){
        while (monthsSinceDiscount>=12){
            // use the inherited setter and getter
            setTotalVisitCost(((20.00 + (12.00*getMonthsSinceVisit())) * 0.20));
            monthsSinceDiscount = 0;
        }
        return getTotalVisitCost();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use protected either, sorry. I believe it has to be done through getters. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: I can't have them set to public or protected, only private. And then I have to use public methods to access those variables. That's what my question is about.

Comment: I understood the question now, and modified my answer, please consider it again.

Comment: @Squatchy97 could you please consider upvoting my question, since I updated the answer I don't believe the answer's current rating reflect it anymore. I also made some observations about inheritance in the code. Thanks

Comment: Sure but it won't affect the publicly displayed score since I don't have 15+ reputation. Thank you for the help, Mário.